# after some time delayed_job is taking more memory in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Delayed is taking more memory after some time. If we restart it, it will come back to form and again after some time it will take more memory. Can anyone please clarify the reason?

Comment: Perhaps, it's leaking memory. In which case, find and fix the leak. Or setup regular restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a memory leak or that it is allocationg more and more memory.

I would suggest not having a very long working job. Instead make a job that goes over all the subbjobs that will be executed an start a job for each of those. Here is a great article explaining that principle but using Sidekiq [Sidekiq Best Practices](https://medium.com/handy-tech/sidekiq-best-practices-cbc2d070a7d4#.8puxq0dyf) but the principle is the same.